# Can't catch input ID when calling JS function from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I don't know why but JavaScript can't catch my input:

```
Mensaje: <input id="mensaje" type="text" name="mensaje" value="" style="width:30%;" placeholder="Escribe un mensaje a enviar...."/>
```

Is built to when I submit the PHP detect it and call the JS function:

```
function ClearFields() {
    var e = document.getElementById("mensaje");
    e.value='';
}
```

My form never reload the page and I can submit a text without reloading. The problem is that the value of textbox is always kept. That's why I'm trying to use JavaScript, to clear this textbox when it is submitted.

I get this error in JS console:

```
(index):24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null(…)
```

Full code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">

    <title>Chat de SL</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            rsdfsdfsd();
            asd();
        });

        function rsdfsdfsd() {
            $('#nax').load('./funcionmensaje.php');
            setTimeout(rsdfsdfsd, 200);
        }

        function ClearFields() {
            var e = document.getElementById("mensaje");
            e.value = '';
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var contador = 0;

        function asd() {
            if (contador < 2) {
                contador++;
                var elem = document.getElementById('nax');
                elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
                setTimeout(asd, 100);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['subname'])) {
                echo '<script>',
                'ClearFields();',
                '</script>'
                ;

        if ($_POST['mensaje'] == "") {

        }
        else {
                file_put_contents('mensajeaenviar', $_POST['mensaje']);
                file_put_contents('var', '0'); 
                $fp = fopen('mensaje.php', 'a');
                $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'].PHP_EOL;
                fwrite($fp, 'Tú: '.$mensaje .'<br>');
            }
        }
    ?>
        <fieldset>
            <font color="#c50000">Lugar:</font> Attached |
            <font color="#c50000">Avatares cercanos:</font>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Chat</legend>

            <td>
                <div id="nax" style="height:70%; overflow:auto">

                </div>
            </td>
        </fieldset>
        <style>
            nax {
                font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
                font-size: 18px;
            }

            fieldset {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                border-radius: 10px;
                background: #eee;
                margin: 20px;
                padding: 20px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
                position: relative;
                border: 2px groove threedface;
            }

            legend {
                position: absolute;
                top: -2px;
                background: #fff;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                border: 2px groove threedface;
                border-top: none;
                box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            legend span {
                display: block;
                margin: -20px;
                background: #fff;
                padding: 0px 20px;
            }

            footer {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                margin-top: 2%;
                background: #ddd;
                border-radius: 5px;
                padding: 15px;
            }

            iframe {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>

        <fieldset style="margin-top:10px;height:3%;">
            <form id="formulario" method="post" target="tar">
                Mensaje: <input id="mensaje" type="text" name="mensaje" value="" style="width:30%;" placeholder="Escribe un mensaje a enviar...." />
                <input type='submit' value='Enviar' name='subname' />

            </form>
        </fieldset>
        <iframe name="tar" src="localhost/a.php">
    </iframe>

</body>
<footer>EnriqueGF Utilities</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Some tips: use meaningful names, remove unused tags and code paths (like the empty `if` branch), avoid inline styles whenever possible, JavaScript can't call PHP functions and vice-versa (without other means, like an API).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You post to the iframe so, as you said yourself, the page is not reloaded and therefore the ClearFields function isn't executed on submit. Add an onsubmit handler to your form and call ClearFields from that.

Comment: Hello! I added the onsubmit the problem is that PHP now can't get values and handle them. Thanks you for your idea.

Comment: Add a `return true` to your onsubmit handler, otherwise the form will not be submitted.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, how do I do that? I actually have:   <form id="formulario" method="post" target="tar" onsubmit="ClearFields() " >

Comment: Just add `return true;`to the end of your ClearFields function.

Comment: Or, alternatively, write `onsubmit="ClearFields(); return true;"`

Comment: Still not working... php is not executing :S, and return true is set

Comment: Just tested it myself and it works (even without the return...). Did you look at the Script-Console? Is there any JavaScript error?

Comment: No, there is no errors, I checked it, that's strange... I only changed what you said, this:   <form id="formulario" method="post" target="tar" onsubmit="ClearFields(); return true;" > and PHP code is not executing... current code: http://pastebin.com/fc5D6Xm5 , really thanks you

Comment: Ohhh... of course. The handler is called **before** the submit so there's nothing to submit after that. Easy workaround would be using window.setTimeout to have the field cleared after some delay. Try replacing the content of the ClearFields function with this: `window.setTimeout(function() {var e = document.getElementById("mensaje");e.value='';}, 1000);`